# PhpStorm how to change default signature for user?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Whenever i create a new file, old developers signature is automatically inserted in the beginning of the file.

I've made some research but nothing helped me so far. Is there a way to change that ?

```
/**
 * Created by old dev
 * Developed by old dev
 * Date: 11.5.2015
 * Time: 08:50
 */
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can modify this signature in *File -> Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Templates -> Includes -> PHP File Header*.

This defaults to your current user system login name.